# Polymorphism: accessing derived class elements from a base class array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic, polymorphism

I haven't worked with derived classes and polymorphism in a while, and I can't figure out how to access a derived class data item.

```
// Quick example
class Base {
  string data1;  // data1 = "FOO"
};
class ChildA : public Base {
  string data2;
};


int main() {
Base **list;
list = new Base*[1];
base[0] = new ChildA(// data2 = "BAR");
std::cout << base[0]->data1; // FOO
std::cout << base[0]->data2; // Error; no member named "data2" in Base
```

Is it possible to retrieve the derived data from the base class array?

Comment: Read about virtual member functions (there is no polymorphism in your sample, whatsoever)

Comment: Access privilege in classes is `private` by default.

Comment: The point about polymorphism is to design your program so that you don't end up doing what your code is doing. The point is you don't want to care about the *specifics* of the type *especially* not what their internal data looks like.

Comment: You might read: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're looking at an instance of a derived class through a pointer to the base class, you can only see the members of the base class, because generally, you wouldn't know what subtype instance you are looking at. The point of polymorphism and virtual functions is that in many cases, you can work with subtype instances without knowing their actual type. For instance, if you want to print information about an instance, and you want `data2` to be included when you print a `ChildA`, you would create a virtual `toString()` function in `Base` and override it in `ChildA` to include `data2`. Then, you can call `toString()` without knowing the actual type, and if your instance is actually a `ChildA`, you'll get `data2`.

Comment: Ahh, that's disappointing. I really thought there was some way to cast it as the type and retrieve the data, but it seems there isn't. This is why you have to practice your old languages every now and then!

Comment: @user3470131: Ah, I didn't understand that you were looking for typecasting. You can do `(static_cast<ChildA*>(base[0]))->data2` if you're sure of the type, or `(dynamic_cast<ChildA*>(base[0]))` if you're not - the latter will produce `NULL` if the type you specify doesn't match the runtime type. But if you need to do this other than for playing around, you might want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

class member variable by default is private.
by using base class pointer, you can not get derived class member var at all.

If you would like to do so, you may want to implement virtual getter function, it will help you getting private member function from derived class.

Answer (score 0):

If the base class interface *must* have knowledge of data potentially held in a derived class, here is one of the few ways that is not horribly dangerous.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::string d1 = {"FOO"} ) : _data1 { std::move(d1) } {}
    virtual ~Base() = default; // because polymorphism without a virtual base class is naughty
    const string& data1() const { return _data1; }

    virtual bool has_data2() const { return false; }
    virtual const string& data2() const {
        throw invalid_argument {"I don't have data2"};
    };

private:
    string _data1;  // data1 = "FOO"
};

class ChildA : public Base {
public:
    ChildA(std::string d2, std::string d1 = {"FOO"})
    : Base { std::move(d1) }
    , _data2 { std::move(d2) }
    {}

    bool has_data2() const override { return true; }
    const std::string& data2() const override {
        return _data2;
    };

private:
    string _data2;
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> bases;
    bases.push_back(unique_ptr<Base>(new ChildA("bob")));
    bases.push_back(unique_ptr<Base>(new Base("not foo")));

    for(const auto& p : bases) {
        cout << p->data1() << ", " << (p->has_data2() ? p->data2() : "no data 2") << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```